# Can't save SSIS solution from other account

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2016

I've created SSIS solution on dev server from windows account1. It saves, complies and runs successfully.

When I try to make changes in same solution from another windows account (account2), it asks me to *re-save the project* at different location.

How can I overcome this? What am I missing? My solution is set for 'EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey'

software: SQL Server 2016 Developer edition. Visual Studio 2015 Shell Integration

Comment: Run VS as administrator that should fix your problem

Comment: Thanks :) Please put up this as answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is too right click `Visual studio` and run it as `Administrator` - Then you will be able to save your ssis-packages without having to resave into another location.